# Flex Fileref... not receiving return result

Tags: php, apache-flex

I'm attempting to upload a file using FileRef and a php script. The file uploads and it definitely returns a test string ( I can see it with a web debugger).. but I can't grab that string in my flex app.  I am using a DataEvent listener and a COMPLETE listener.  Still no result.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
fileRef.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, onFileResponse);
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileRef_complete);

private function fileRef_complete(evt:Event):void{

     trace("COMPLETE");
     trace(evt.target.data);

    }

private function onFileResponse(event:DataEvent)
    {
     message.text = "HELLO";
     trace("UPLOAD COMPLETE = " + event.data);


    }
```

Comment: Not sure but I would like to know. We had this problem using a ColdFusion Component before. We worked around it by doing the file upload completely in a browser in an iframe of the flex app, took the flash player out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue that the events are not being fired, or that `data` field is empty when the events are fired?

If the former, is the server returning HTTP code 200?  That's the only direct specification I see in the [`FileReference`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html) docs.

If the latter, I don't think it's expected for the data field to be populated on an upload() call:

> data:ByteArray [read-only]
>
> The ByteArray object representing the
>   data from the loaded file after a
>   successful call to the load() method.

---

Edit:

Does the `FileReference` go out of scope before the call is complete--that will cancel the transaction from the Flash end (though the call may still complete on the web end).

How are you calling `FileReference.upload()`?  I assume that's not the issue if your web debugger shows success, but it may be of interest.

Comment: the events aren't being fired at all.  Even a simple trace isn't firing on the event.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i'm calling file upload:

```
fileRef.upload(urlReq, "Filedata", false);
```

It shouldn't be going out of scope, it's in the same mxml doc, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Perhaps if you edited the main question with a full example (stripped down to just what's needed to replicate)?

Comment: I figured it out, was just calling everything in the wrong order. As soon as I put the event listeners after the file was selected then it worked fine.